# Which protections can I use on the server

Tags: linux, selinux, fail2ban, firewalld, mod-security

I have read about server protection and I know how to work with fewalld protection because it is not demanding.

My question is:
Which of the following protections is best for the server and which of the offered ones can be used together on the server :

1. Firewalld
2. Fail2ban
3. Mod_security
4. Mod_Evasive
5. Selinux

Thank you!

Comment: to be honest the minimum hardening of a server already needs all of them + advanced ssh/ssl/pgp keys setup.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Ok so I can install firewalld also with Mod_security and there will be no problem (because that is two firewalls on the server)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the products / tools you list have a different focus and target different threats/aspects of system security. One is not intrinsically better than the other.

The use of one does also not exclude the usage of any of the others. You can use them in concert to create a limited form of [defense in depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_(computing)).

The only thing missing from your list is arguably the most important, especially on systems directly connected to the internet:

- regularly apply all relevant security updates and bug fixes

Comment: Bob, thank you for the answer. I understand, so there is no conflict running the services with firewalld and mod_security. Thank you.  For the regularly security updated , that is something that I do manually .